# paraview color map package availability

Tags: python, colormap, paraview

My solution filed is symmetrical about zero, so I have like +100, and -100. I have a 5.9 paraview, but all the color map is not good for me, is there any package to download?

Answer (score 0):

There is no packages specific to ParaView.

To use more color map, first be sure you switch from `Default` to `All` in the Choose Preset Dialog (at the top, next to the search bar).

You also can import xml/json files that describe a color map. I didn't find the doc about the file structure, so one way is to export an  existent colormap and modify it. Or find some in the Internet.

[Here](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/color-map-advice-and-resources/6452) are some resources about colormaps. And [here](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/colorMapping.html?highlight=preset#mapping-data) about editing existing colormap in ParaView.